# After joining meshes they become white

Tags: mirror, subdivision-surface

Is this normal? Becouse it does it only with some meshes. I have applied "Subdivision Surface" and "Mirror" (with clipping enabled) to the parts that become white. I didn't apply mirror to the final part of the mag, and is not becoming white even if it joins other parts, so i guess the problem is there? How do i solve it? 
[image: Before]
[image: After]
Also, side question, how do i get back the "file/render/window" tab on the top of the screen? I have it in other views (like in UV editing view or scripting view) but i don't have it in the default view, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried in Edit Mode selecting all and Recalculating Normals?

Comment: Tried it now, it doesn't work

Comment: I solved it by removing the bottom part and create it by extruding the top part (joining the two top parts didn't create the problem)